# Ajax success returns correct data, but jQuery replace leaves screen 'visually' blank

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here we go again...

VS 2012 MVC 5, bootstrap 3.1.1, jQuery 2.1.0, JQuery UI combined 1.10.4, MS jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax 3.1.1

I have a form:

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Catalog")" data-cs-ajax="true" data-cs-target="#productList">
```

you'll note the data- attributes like Scot Allen's OdeToFood example...

I got to the form because someone clicked a category link (category 15) in my catalog.
So the original URL request is

/home/catalog/15

The page looks like this (it's still very simple)...

[image: Initial Page load]

On the form I have  a DropDownListFor:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.CategoryItems, new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
```

When you selet an item in the dropdown, the page submits.

I also have some jQuery:

```
$(function () {

var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-cs-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
      //  var options = {};
        //$newHtml.effect("highlight");
        //$newHtml.effect("highlight", options, 500, doneEffect);
    });

    return false;
};
```

This is fired via a bit of Query which is also in the document ready function...

```
$("form[data-cs-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
```

So, you don't like what you see in the catalog, and go ahead to select a different catalog category which set's @Model.Id - the category...

When you break just before the ajax call in javascript:

```
 $.ajax(options)
```

the options look like:

```
    -   options {...}   Object
    +   __proto__   {...}   Object
    data    "Id=16" String
    type    "get"   String
    url "/home/Catalog/15"  String
```

ok - so here's annoying 'feature' #1.

Why isn't the url now /home/Catalog/16 ??

Onward...

SO you go to the server, get the new category items and return it via a partial view...

```
public ActionResult Catalog(int Id = 0, int page=1)
```

I understood the new category in the controller action because I added a hack (I hate this):

```
if (Request.Params["Id"] != null)
{
   Id = int.Parse(Request.Params["Id"]); // here, Request.Params["Id"] was 16 and not the url Id 15
}
```

when it goes back to the jQUery success callback:

```
       $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-cs-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        var options = {};
        $newHtml.effect("highlight", options, 500, doneEffect);
    });
```

It properly finds and replaces the returned HTML for the new bunch of items from the new category.

However... now for awesome 'feature' #2

When the final web page is rendered, all items are now all somehow hidden...arg...They are all correctly rendered, but noting is visible

[image: Highlighted area with f12 debug features in IE]

SO my questions are: -

1. Why doesn't the ID update the route value instead of just stay as a Request.Param?
2. What the heck with the hidden results? How do I get my items to show?

Any help appreciated

[EDIT:] - I think the visibility thing is from having my js files loaded in the wrong order - I'll verify. Still need help with the route value not changing to the new Id value - even on a 'get'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for a Javascript library/piece of code to interpret the routing set up the the MVC backend?

Can't really be done like that. The browser has no idea what kind of backend is being referred. It could just as well be a PHP-driven backend, and the routing values are completely different. The `15` could be a session cookie. Or a subdirectory. You simply can't know.

What you actually want as the URL is `/Home/Catalog` (without anything added).

It is strange, however, that `@Url.Action("Catalog")` would include any attribute when not specified. I have multiple projects in which I perform the exact same task, and it just leaves me with `"/controller/method"`.

I get the feeling that something on the page is changing the form action from the *correct* URL to the *current* URL. Can you try literally pasting `@Url.Action("Catalog")` in your code? Something like this:

```
var options = {
    url: "@Url.Action("Catalog")", //notice the additional "quotes"!
    type: $form.attr("method"),
    data: $form.serialize()
};
```

Assuming that doesn't fix it, we can still fix it manually.

First of all: `/Home/Catalog/16` and `/Home/Catalog?id=16` are equal. The former is just a shorthand notation of the latter.
But if you combine the two: `/Home/Catalog/15?id=16`, the `/15` overrules the `?id=16` parameter.

Since your Ajax call is currently posting both id's at the same time, you keep requesting the page for ID 15. This explains why you don't see any changes.

To fix this, all you need to do is make sure that the `/15` doesn't get added to the ajax url. There are some ways to do this, some more preferable than others:

- As mentioned before, `@Url.Action("Catalog")` should do the trick. Try pasting it in directly, to prevent any rogue code snippet from wrongly altering the form action somewhere between page load and form submit. Also, if that doesn't work, try hardcoding the URL. I'm convinced your code should work as intended, but there's probably some outside influence at work here.
- You can cut off the last part manually: `var correctURL = wrongURL.substring(0, wrongURL.lastIndexOf('/'));`. It's a blunt way of correcting it, but if everything else fails...
- There are other ways, but they're either equally or more risky than the previous suggestion.

Let me know if you find the cause of the changed URL.